# Get all items with min values SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's what the table is like:

```
----------------------------------
   EmployeeId      Tasks_Count
   1               1
   2               1
   3               2
   4               1
   5               3
```

I need a query to get all employees with min tasks count. Result should be like this:

```
---------------
   EmployeeId   
   1               
   2               
   4
```

The problem is that i using a subquery to count tasks. Here's my code

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT EmployeeId,
             COUNT(*) AS Tasks_count
      FROM Tasks
      INNER JOIN Status ON Tasks.StatusId=Status.Id
      WHERE Status.Name != 'Closed'
      GROUP BY EmployeeId
      ORDER BY Tasks_count DESC) AS Employee_not_closed
WHERE Tasks_count IN (SELECT MIN(Tasks_count) 
                      FROM Employee_not_closed)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `FETCH FIRST WITH TIES`:

```
select EmployeeId
from tablename
order by Tasks_Count
fetch first 1 row with ties
```

Comment: Very similar to select top 1 with ties...I wasn't aware of this alternative.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis, FETCH FIRST is the ANSI SQL version.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below -

```
select * from tablename
where Tasks_Count in (select min(Tasks_Count) from tablename)
```

Answer (score 2):

It can also be done using `RANK()` function like following.

```
;with cte as
(
   select Employeeid, rank() over( order by Tasks_Count) rn
   from @table
)
select * from cte where rn=1
```

Answer (score 2):

You Can use the below code i have tested the code and its working fine.

```
select EmployeeId from StackOverFlow_3 where Tasks_Count in(select min(Tasks_Count) from StackOverFlow_3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  a  join on subquery

```
    select m.EmployeeId 
    from my_table  m
    inner join  
    (
        select min(task_count) min_task
        from my_table 
    ) t  on t.min_task = m.task_count
```